# Jquery: how to extract all paragraphs between 2 HNs tags?

Tags: jquery

I need to extract text between 2 HNs
Normal document is created that way:

```
<h1>title1</h1>
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>

<h2>title2</h2>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
<p>paragraph 4</p>

<h2>title3</h2>
<p>paragraph 5</p>
<p>paragraph 6</p>

<h3>title4</h3>
<div>
  <p>paragraph 7</p>
  <p>paragraph 8</p>
</div>
```

My goal is to extract text paragraphs into Array
To extract HNs, I use:

```
Array.from(jQuery(":header"))
```

But no idea on how to extract all p tags between 2 H tags

So final result should be

```
["paragraph 1 paragraph 2", "paragraph 3 paragraph 4", "paragraph 5 paragraph 6", "paragraph 7 paragraph 8"]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d1g50v74/1/

Answer (score 1):

One option is to just iterate through `h` or `<p>` elements. When you find a `p`, push its text to an array, and when you find an `h`, reassign the array for the next group:

```js
const arrOfTextGroups = [];
let currentTextGroup = [];
[...container.querySelectorAll('p, h1, h2, h3')]
  .forEach((elm) => {
    if (elm.matches('p')) {
      currentTextGroup.push(elm.textContent);
    } else {
      currentTextGroup = []
      arrOfTextGroups.push(currentTextGroup);
    }
  });

const output = arrOfTextGroups.map(textArr => textArr.join(' '));
console.log(output);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1>title1</h1>
  <p>paragraph 1</p>
  <p>paragraph 2</p>

  <h2>title2</h2>
  <p>paragraph 3</p>
  <p>paragraph 4</p>

  <h2>title3</h2>
  <p>paragraph 5</p>
  <p>paragraph 6</p>

  <h3>title4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>paragraph 7</p>
    <p>paragraph 8</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [the sibling selector](https://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) in this case:

```
$(":header ~ p")
```

But it does not match the case where paragraphs are inside the div, so you can use something like this to handle that case too:

```
$(":header ~ p, :header ~ * p")
```

So the complete code can be:

```
Array.from($(":header ~ p, :header ~ * p")).map(el => el.textContent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use a regex to split the content and grabbing the text content from the splitted parts.

```js
const str = `<h1>title1</h1>
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>

<h2>title2</h2>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
<p>paragraph 4</p>

<h2>title3</h2>
<p>paragraph 5</p>
<p>paragraph 6</p>

<h3>title4</h3>
<div>
  <p>paragraph 7</p>
  <p>paragraph 8</p>
</div>`

console.log(str.split(/<h.>.*<\/h.>/).map(s => $(s).text()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```